# Why Sikuli API not able to click Window image for the first time? Works when repeated.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli

When the file upload window opens, it doesn't click for first time. I close it manually then click again to open the dialog, this time Sikuli proceeds with execution.
Using selenium webdriver to automate file upload with Sikuli API. Please find below code:

```
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/nitin.chawda/Desktop/example1.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("usage")).click();
Screen screen = new Screen();
screen.wait("images\\location1.png",100).doubleClick();
screen.wait("images\\file1.png",100).click();
screen.wait("images\\open.png",100).click();
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't click for the first time." Is Sikuli able to move the mouse to the correct position? Does Sikuli raise a FindFailed error?

Comment: It stays there forever unless i do manual interaction with the window. Neither the mouse move happens nor the test case execution proceeds. Then i close the window manually and reopen the file upload dialog manually. This time it works. Not sure if it has got anything to do with focus for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your click *is happening* the first time, but not doing what you'd expect.

If the window you're trying to click is not in focus, then, rather than preforming some other action, the first click will focus that window, .

Try using the `App.focus("WINDOW-NAME");` classmethod before the Sikuli clicks. (where "WINDOW-NAME" is a string matching the name of your file upload window)

Resources:

- [App Class from Sikuli docs](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/appclass.html#open-close-and-focus-an-application)
- [App Class from the javadoc](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/App.html)

Comment: I have given a try using `App app = new App("File Upload");  app.focus();` before click but same issue

Answer (score 0):

just use screen.click(), it will enable the window focused.